# How can I evaluate HTML depth in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm writing a PHP framework right now, and have run into somewhat of a formatting problem.

My intention is to load in a combination of a few files, compile them all together, and kick them out as their appropriate HTML. In this process, I intend to indent or outdent as I progress line to line. Right now, I use a combination of simple checks for '<', '&lt/' and '/&gt', ( Couldn't use the real character here ) alongside some XML parsing to achieve this, but I'm sure that there is a better way to do this.

Right now my code gives me something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Your Sitename - Module - Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/layout/default/css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="php/plugins/MoviePlayer/windows/IE/Silverlight/css/silverlight.css" type="text/css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Cookies.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/GlobalReady.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PluginDetection.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Silverlight.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flow.1.2.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="layout/layout/default/js/LayoutInit.js"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript" src="php/plugins/MoviePlayer/windows/IE/Silverlight/js/SLPlayer.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="php/plugins/MoviePlayer/windows/IE/Silverlight/js/wmvplayer.js"></script>
             </head>
              <body onLoad="javascript: GlobalReady();">
               <div id="container">
                <div id="header">
                 </div>
                </div>
               </body>
              </html>
```

Which is a little off of what I am trying to achieve.

I'm not any sort of regular expression expert; or user even, and I assume that I could achieve this in that manner, but wouldn't know how to go about it.

Effectively, my question is this; how would You approach formatting this properly ( programatically ), if you were printing it out one line at a time? Is there a library that could identify all of the elements on a single line, regardless of their association with a later element?

If not I'm sure I'll be writing a new class to handle this on my own.

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Your Sitename - Module - Index</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/layout/default/css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="php/plugins/MoviePlayer/windows/IE/Silverlight/css/silverlight.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Cookies.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/GlobalReady.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PluginDetection.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Silverlight.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flow.1.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="layout/layout/default/js/LayoutInit.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="php/plugins/MoviePlayer/windows/IE/Silverlight/js/SLPlayer.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="php/plugins/MoviePlayer/windows/IE/Silverlight/js/wmvplayer.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Is formatting everything at once an option? If so, I would use HTML_TIDY.

Comment: How are you getting such code? What's generating it?

Comment: Formatting everything at once isn't an option, thank you for asking. Right now I run through my 'final' output line by line, and upon encountering PHP inside of said content, I gather it all up and eval it. Whenever I print, inside of a content file or not, I currently reference a 'layout->writeline' method, that tracks indentation; just not so fantastically.

Comment: And the code is being generated by a 3000 line CMS that I'm in the middle of writing.

Comment: @DigitalJedi805: That code is flawed if it generates such HTML. You should open a different question about it and provide the relevant piece of code that is responsible for generating HTML.

Comment: @Truth; Yes I'm aware; this is why I'm asking how someone else would approach it, thus why I didn't post any of the code that generated this... I could write a large piece of code to yield a better result, but I know that there are better approaches. Thus why I specified, that my question was 'How would <someone else> go about determining what's on each of these lines'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load a few files, concatenate them into a string, and use **[`tidy`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php)** to format them.

However, it's most likely a problem with the code generating the HTML, that should be fixed instead of outputting malformed code and fixing it later.

Comment: While this is a great suggestion; I have the possibility of executing a 'writeline' in the middle of my output, I.E. 'Load the layout, insert the content, start printing, evaluating php inside of content', and I'd like this code to come out formatted as well; which means that I should reference my 'Layout->WriteLine' for all write methods ( even inside of my content files ); which also means that it needs to maintain a running record of how far indented I am, which is why I currently seek out key 'phrases'.

Comment: @DigitalJedi805: See [output buffering control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

Comment: Possibly very useful. Thank you, and I'll have to experiment with it.